# Prevent css transition depending on window size

Tags: jquery, css, resize, css-transitions

What is a common practice to prevent css transitions when resizing window?

In my example https://jsfiddle.net/f3c9e4n7/3/ with different windows size, during the "on" state, element animates to another position. I can prevent animation by adding an extra class with `transition: none;` with a timeout like here: https://jsfiddle.net/f3c9e4n7/2/.

What is a better practice to go about this? Adding timeout function seems like not the most elegant solution.

```
$(".el").click(function() {
  if ( $(this).hasClass("off") ) {
    $(this).removeClass("off");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".el").addClass("notransition");
    }, 650);
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("notransition");
    $(this).addClass("off");
  }
});
```

Comment: i'm not totally sure on what you want to achieve, but why not working only with media-queries to choose which transition you want to use?
i mean, define your element once per all the media queries and then define the media-queries to specify the color and the transition. According to these, you can simply adjust your javascript in order to work only with certain widths.

Comment: i would like to prevent elements animation on resize during "on" state, this is simplified fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f3c9e4n7/4/. i'm not sure how i can apply your suggestion in my case.

Comment: mmm so if the block has been translated, if i resize the window, the block should remain in that position/color and ignore the css?  something like this https://jsfiddle.net/f3c9e4n7/8/ using the resize event?

Comment: when window is smaller then 425 the block should stay at the right, when window is bigger then 425 the block should stay at the bottom. imagine it is a switch witch changes direction on mq.